# How to append a string to subset of variable names in R?

Tags: r, rename

I am trying to alter a select few of my variable names in a data frame. How can I do this without typing each of the old names and each of the new names? I thought the code below might work but it hasn't. I am trying to append "Econ" to each of the existing names identified in the data frame.

```
    names(wb.misc)[3,13,14,20,22,47,61,62,64,68,73] <- 
         paste("Econ", names(wb.misc)[3,13,14,20,22,47,61,62,64,68,73], sep = "-")
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What error do you get?

Comment: welcome to SO :) [you might like #005](http://www.twotorials.com/)

Answer (score 10):

You need to put `c()` around the indices

```
 names(wb.misc)[c(3,13,14,20,22,47,61,62,64,68,73)] = paste("Econ", names(wb.misc)[c(3,13,14,20,22,47,61,62,64,68,73)], sep = "-")
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to efficiently get the variable names is to use `dput(names(df))` where `df` is your data.frame.

For example, using the built-in dataset `airquality`, you can do the following

```
dput(names(airquality))
```

Which gives you:

```
c("Ozone", "Solar.R", "Wind", "Temp", "Month", "Day")
```

You can then edit to extract the columns you want without having to type them from scratch. E.g., say you want to rename the following three variables, you could use `rename.vars` in `gdata`.

```
vars <- c("Ozone",  "Wind", "Temp")
library(gdata)
rename.vars(airquality, from=vars, to=paste0("Econ", vars))
```

Using actual variable names will also generally make your code more reliable.