# Rename Column in R based on Dataframe name

Tags: r, dataframe, data-binding, merge, dplyr

I have multiple dataframes with the same column names. I'd like to merge them, but rename the columns based on the names of the dataframes.

Current State:

```
Dataframe1:

Date          Price
12/1/1990     10.00
12/2/1990     11.00
12/3/1990     12.00

Dataframe2:

Date          Price
12/1/1990     11.00
12/2/1990     12.00
12/3/1990     14.00
```

Desired State:

```
Date          DataFrame1Price   DataFrame2Price
12/1/1990     10.00             11.00
12/2/1990     11.00             12.00
12/3/1990     12.00             14.00
```

Comment: You have to divide your task into smaller doable tasks. First, merge dataframe, then rename columns. 1. [How to merge dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right); 2. [How to rename columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame/7532464).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Dataframe1 <- data.frame(Date = c('12/1/1990' , '12/2/1990' , '12/3/1990'), 
                          Price = c(10, 11, 12)))
#>        Date Price
#> 1 12/1/1990    10
#> 2 12/2/1990    11
#> 3 12/3/1990    12
(Dataframe2 <- data.frame(Date = c('12/1/1990' , '12/2/1990' , '12/3/1990'), 
                          Price = c(11, 12, 14)))
#>        Date Price
#> 1 12/1/1990    11
#> 2 12/2/1990    12
#> 3 12/3/1990    14

merge(Dataframe1, Dataframe2, by = 'Date', suffixes = c(".Dataframe1",".Dataframe2"))
#>        Date Price.Dataframe1 Price.Dataframe2
#> 1 12/1/1990               10               11
#> 2 12/2/1990               11               12
#> 3 12/3/1990               12               14
```

or with `_join` from `dplyr`

```
> # install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

Dataframe2 %>% 
       full_join(Dataframe2, 
               by = c("Date"), suffix = c(".Dataframe2", ".Dataframe2"))
> #        Date Price.Dataframe2 Price.Dataframe2.Dataframe2
> # 1 12/1/1990               11                          11
> # 2 12/2/1990               12                          12
> # 3 12/3/1990               14                          14
```

Answer (score 0):

A [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) approach to solving your problem would be to bind the rows in long format with an *id* representing the source data frame and then using `spread` to switch to wide format as required.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Date = c('12/1/1990' , '12/2/1990' , '12/3/1990'),
  Price = c(10, 11, 12)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Date = c('12/1/1990' , '12/2/1990' , '12/3/1990'),
  Price = c(11, 12, 14)
)

df <- bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, .id = "source") %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  transmute(
    source,
    date = mdy(Date),
    price = Price
  )

df

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   source date       price
#   <chr>  <date>     <dbl>
# 1 df1    1990-12-01  10.0
# 2 df1    1990-12-02  11.0
# 3 df1    1990-12-03  12.0
# 4 df2    1990-12-01  11.0
# 5 df2    1990-12-02  12.0
# 6 df2    1990-12-03  14.0

df %>% spread(source, price)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   date         df1   df2
#   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1990-12-01  10.0  11.0
# 2 1990-12-02  11.0  12.0
# 3 1990-12-03  12.0  14.0
```