# rename the category of variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have text variable  `X1`. It takes value `A,B,C,D`. I need to rename category D to F. So in output i expect `A,B,C,F`
How can i  do it?
here my dataset

```
mydat=structure(list(x1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d"), class = "factor"), x2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x3 = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace a value in a data frame based on a conditional (\`if\`) statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement)

Comment: Like this: `factor(mydat$x1, labels=c("A","B","C","F"))`?

Comment: in my case there are 100 000 lables

Comment: See `dplyr::recode` or the `forcats` package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename a single column in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to characters, use simple subsetting and convert it back to a factor (optional):

```
mydat$x1 <- as.character(mydat$x1)
mydat$x1[mydat$x1 == 'd'] <- 'f'
# optional
mydat$x1 <- as.factor(mydat$x1)
```

Or - as you were looking for a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>%
  mutate(x1 = as.character(x1),
         x1 = if_else(x1 == 'd', 'f', x1),
         x1 = as.factor(x1))
```

Both will yield

```
  x1 x2 x3
1  a  1  2
2  b  1  2
3  c  1  2
4  f  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the category is a factor variable, you can simply rename using `recode` with `mutate` from `dplyr`.

For example:

```
mydat %>%
  mutate(x1 = recode(x1, d=f))
```