# Assign new column names if a dataframe's name is called as a string variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame, the name of which is wrapped in a variable "my_var". What I am trying to do is to assign a new column names for this data.

What I have tried is:

```
names(get(my_var)) <- c("Fruits", "Sweets")
```

```
assign(names(get(my_var)),  c("Fruits", "Sweets"))
```

```
within (get(my_var), assign(names(get(my_var)),  c("Fruits", "Sweets")))
```

Neither of this works.

Thanks

Comment: To rename columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame

Comment: “the name of which is wrapped in a variable "my_var"” — Why? This is something that’s generally to avoid. *If* you need computed names, use named list items. And then your code works: `names(the_list[[my_var]]) = c('Fruits', 'Sweets')`.

Comment: I am producing data frames from files on the fly and I need to name the data frames as the file's name

Comment: @MirrG In that case, put them into a list as mentioned. Alternatively, if they all have the same data shape, it may make more sense to load them all into the *same* table, via something like purrr’s `map_dfr` function.

Comment: @MirrG The point is that when creating data frames on the fly, the way to do that is to put them in a named list, so they can be easily referred to using a character variable representing the list element name. Relying on things like `get` and `assign` will often lead to more problems down the road.

Comment: KonradRudolph, joran, thank you. What I am doing is trying to write a function that takes arbitrary .csv, prepare a dataframe and doing some math with it. So I have "function (file) { name=strsplit(file, "\\.")[[1]][1];  df <- read.csv(file, sep=";"); assign(name, df)  .... } " . If I understood  correctly, I should write "name" in a list and then assign it to data? my_list[1] <- read.csv(file, sep=";") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setnames` from the `data.table` package:

```
setnames(get(my_var), names(get(my_var)), c('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: Metariat, thank you. Which package is this function from? I don't have it in 'base' or 'dplyr'.

Comment: answer enriched