# How to rename a column with the content of its left column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a different columns, namely one with the date, one with a stock ticker (remains the same in the whole column) and one with the stock price on each date. This data frame contains the stock prices of all S&P500 stocks.

I wish to remove the column with the ticker and put it as the title of the column with the corresponding stock price.

[image: 1]

to see how it looks like

Comment: Hi Juriv, they are many SO posts about naming columns (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7531868/10264278). Please do not post screenshot, it is very hard to use them. Consider posting the code you have tried so far and check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). For example, to produce a minimal data set, you can use `head()`, `subset()`. Then use `dput()` to give us something that can be put in R immediately. Alternatively, you can use base R datasets (to see complete list `library(help = "datasets")`).

Comment: rename column:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame

Comment: drop column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop data frame columns by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name)

Comment: I think you want to reshape your data. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: `idx <- grep('Ticker', names(data)); names(data)[idx + 1] <- sapply(data[idx], unique); data[idx] <- NULL`

Comment: Thank you @rawr, this is exactly what I needed! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This operation is called [pivoting](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html). You want to bring that data from its long into a wide form. This can be achieved with `data.table::dcast` or `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

Note, that a long format is usually desired for manipulation (e.g. `tidyr` or `data.table`) plotting (with `ggplot2`) or printing `ggtable`. Machine learning functions usually requires a wide format input though.