# plot_ordination function of phyloseq plots shapes 'double' within itself

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I'm analysing NGS data using the `phyloseq` package. I want to create a PCoA (Bray-curtis DM) plot using following code:

```
ord_bc_pcoa<-ordinate(physeq,method="PCoA", distance="bray")

pcoa_plot_1<-plot_ordination(physeq,ord_bc_pcoa,color="variable1", shape="variable2") + 
    geom_point(size=4) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("var1X"="red","var1Y"="#55BE25","var1Z"="blue")) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c("var2A"=0,"var2B"=2,"var2C"=3,"var2D"=4,"var2D"=5,"var2E"=6,"varF"=7,"var2G"=8)) +
    ggtitle("title1")
pcoa_plot_1
```

In the resulting plot, the shapes look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the shapes are plotted twice, at a different size within eachother. Also, if I would manually assign a 'filled' shape to a variable (e.g. shape code 22), it also does not appeared filled on the plot, but still has a empty fill.

When I run another `geom_point()` plot of ggplot2, I do get the good looking shapes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To improve the appearance and give you more control of your plot, I would recommend that you extract your PCoA data, merge in your metadata, and use ggplot to make your plot. The steps you should take:

1. Perform the PCoA ordination

`library(phyloseq)`

`ord_bc_pcoa <- ordinate(physeq,method="PCoA", distance="bray")`

2. Save the PCoA vectors data from your ordinated object

`vectors <- as.data.frame(ord_bc_pcoa$vectors)`

3. Change the rownames into a column and name this column the name "SampleID"

`library(tibble)`

`vectors <- rownames_to_column(vectors, "SampleID")`

4. Save the metadata slot in your phyloseq object as its own data object, making sure that the sample column has the same name used in step 3 to allow the joining in step 5 (this step *assumes* that your sample column is automatically a rowname. If not: [rename your sample column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame) to "SampleID").

`metadata <- rownames_to_column(data.frame(physeq@sam_data), "SampleID")`

5. Use the `inner_join()` function to merge the metadata information with the PCoA data, where they will be joined by the "SampleID" column

`library(dplyr)`

`vectors_metadata <- dplyr::inner_join(vectors, metadata, by = "SampleID")`

6. Use this data object in ggplot to plot your data

`library(ggplot2)`

`ggplot(vectors_metadata, aes(x = Axis.1, y = Axis.2, color = variable1, shape = variable2)) + geom_point()`

Where you can use the [standard ggplot design options](http://sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-scatter-plots-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) to customise your plot to a higher degree than with the `plot_ordination` function alone.

Comment: dear Jessie, thanks for your suggestion! BTW, the answer to my question was that I had to remove ``` geom_point(size=4)``` as this is already done in the command.