# How to use lapply for rename single column in list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

I refer to [How to rename a single column in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame)?

```
# df = dataframe
# old.var.name = The name you don't like anymore
# new.var.name = The name you want to get
names(df)[names(df) == 'old.var.name'] <- 'new.var.name'
```

I want to use this way(or other rename way?)

```
names(df)[names(df) == 'old.var.name'] <- 'new.var.name'
```

lapply for multi-layer list to rename single column, but I don't know
how it iterate for sublist(such as following iris1, iris2 and iris3), let sublist rename column 'Species' to 'newSpecies'.

(If you know relevant tutorials on lapply processing multi-layer list/dataframe, you can also recommend it to me.)

```
irisData <- list(iris1 = iris, iris2 = iris, iris3 = iris)
colnames(irisData$iris1)
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width" 
#[3] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#[5] "Species"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` like this.

```
> irisData <- lapply(irisData, \(x) {names(x)[names(x) == 'Species'] <- 'newSpecies'; x})
> lapply(irisData, head, 2)
$iris1
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width newSpecies
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa

$iris2
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width newSpecies
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa

$iris3
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width newSpecies
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

---

*Data:*

```
irisData <- list(iris1=iris, iris2=iris, iris3=iris)
```

Comment: Very thanks for your help!!

Comment: May I ask '; x' mean? I can't find any relevant explanation, or maybe I'm searching for wrong keywords

Comment: @ninaPeng You could think of `;` as a new line operator, first the names of x are changed, then the entire x is returned. This is kinda shorthand, you could also use two lines instead.